# use a maven archetype from java

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

I am trying to write a project/code generator in java and would like to use maven archetypes as a base (90% of the code is the same). I have an archetype, but I can't seem to generate the code from the archetype. I have tried using the Maven-Embedder, but no luck so far. I have been looking at the maven archetype plugin, but can't seem to find any simple example code to generate the project. Can anyone guide me to some sort of example?

What I do now (and doesn't seem to work):

```java
    String location = "/path/to/generate/to";
    MavenCli maven = new MavenCli();
    String[] mavenArguments = new String[]{"archetype:generate", "-DgroupId=xxx", "-DartifactId=yyy", etc.}
    maven.doMain(mavenArguments, location, System.out, System.out);
```

All I get from this is -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set.

Comment: I would say the official doc is a good starting point: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html or a complete example at: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-archetype

Comment: This is about creating the archetype. I already have this. What I don't know is how to use the archetype from a java application

Comment: Have you tried to execute it as a command line? Still from Java but you execute the command directly instead of using a java client

Comment: when running the command in command line, the project generates when run in the desired path

Comment: Or do you mean to run the command in some sort of commandline library?

Comment: not sure you need the whole maven thing to do that. a lot of maven plugins are wrappers around functionality elsewhere. so a good starting point for inspiration might be the generate mojo itself: https://github.com/apache/maven-archetype/blob/maven-archetype-3.2.0/maven-archetype-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/archetype/mojos/CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java